# How to put an input box that whatever the user puts in will put in a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test()
    'insert input box to ask user to decrease by how much
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F1:F" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-0.56"<------ .56 would be what the user puts in the input box
End Sub
```

This is my current code but I can't seem to figure out how to put an input box where the user will decide how much to decrease it by.

Comment: Keep in mind that when using an inputbox, especially for numeric values, the user input should be validated before it is used. In other words, make sure to check to see if their input would cause an error if it was used and prompt them again in that case, or just explain to them in a popup that their input was not valid and that the function would not continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call an `InputBox`.

```
Sub test()
    'insert input box to ask user to decrease by how much
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim amt As String
    Do While Not IsNumeric(amt)
        amt = Application.InputBox("What is the amount to reduce by?")
    Loop
    Range("F1:F" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-" & amt
End Sub
```

Note: This does *absolutely no* validation on the input, except to check that it's a number. That's an exercise I've left for the reader. ;)